# How to have a button run while it is being pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to have a method continuously run while a button is pressed. At the moment the method only runs once when the UI button is pressed. I've tried implementing a coroutine but I couldn't figure out a way a condition for StopCoroutine() to run. I've also tried using the event triggers PointerUp and PointerDown that set a boolean to false and true that determine if a coroutine runs or not but that seemed to work.
Would anyone know how to implement a continuous on button hold? Any help is appreciated.

**The method I want to continuously run while the button is held. This method is called in a PointerDown event trigger in the UI button.**

```
public void spawnLaser()
    {
        GameObject laser = Instantiate(laserprefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(laserSpeed, 0);
    }
```

Comment: You want to Instantiate a new object every frame?

Answer (score 0):

[Input.GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) returns true during the frame the user starts pressing down the key identified by name, while [Input.GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name.
Seems you need to give Input.GetKey a try.

To keep it calling while pressed, call it from the `Update()`.

```
public void spawnLaser()
{
    GameObject laser = Instantiate(laserprefab, transform.position, 
    Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(laserSpeed, 0);
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("up"))
    {
        print("up arrow key is held down");
        spawnLaser();
    }
}
```

Comment: The question posted shows using a coroutine and when I try to implement a coroutine with pointer and pointerDown i receive an error due to trying to stop a coroutine that hasn't started. And I'm unsure how to add a condition that sets a boolean true and false when the button is not being pressed

Comment: The input.GetKey won't work for this type of behaviour due to not wanting to use buttons to run this method but rather the button. I already have something similar to the GeyKey for keyboard controls

Comment: dont use a coroutine, call it from the update

Comment: why a coroutine??

Comment: also when you got it workling you are going to have lots of objects instantiated according to your method. Check if that is what you want

Comment: Yes once working i want this method to be run every X seconds. Maybe around every 0.3 seconds

Comment: then check mr @derHugo's answer, seems to be what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

In general you can just implement the [`IPointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html), [`IPointerUpHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html), [`IPointerExitHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerExitHandler.html) and [`IPointerEnterHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) interfaces like e.g.

```
public class WhilePressedButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public UnityEvent whilePressed;

    // adjust according to your needs via the Inspector
    [Min(0f)] public float delay = 0.3f;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StartCoroutine(ContinuousButton());
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // Actually not really needed
        // but not sure if maybe required for having OnPointerExit work
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    private IEnumerator ContinuousButton()
    {
        // Whut? o.O
        // No worries, this is fine in a Coroutine as long as you yield somewhere inside
        while (true)
        {

            whilePressed.Invoke();

            // Very important for not freezing the editor completely!
            // This tells unity to "pause" the routine here
            // render the current frame and continue
            // from this point on the next frame

            // If you want some delay between calls
            if(delay > 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (delay);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise it directly contineus in the next frame
                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And reference your `spawnLaser` method in `whilePressed` like usually in a Button `onClick` via the Inspector or in code.

Note: This is either on an UI element such as a `UI.Button` or on a 3D object with a collider but then you additionally require a `PhysicsRaycaster` component on your `Camera`.

**You do NOT need an `EventTrigger` component for this!** The interface methods `OnPointerXY` will simply be called by the UI itself!

---

However, are you really going to Instantiate a new object **every frame** while the button is pressed?

You should probably checkout [Object Pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling) or in general only activate and deactivate your object instead of Instantiate and delete it over and over again.

Answer (score -1):

According to Unity Documentation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;// Required when using Event data.

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler// required interface when using the OnPointerDown method.
{
    //Do this when the mouse is clicked over the selectable object this script is attached to.
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " Was Clicked.");
    }
}
```

Add the `IPointerDownHandler` interface to your class and implement the `OnPointerDown(PointerEventData)` method.

I recommend using a `bool` to track the state of the button (e.g `true` if pressed) and then in your `Update()` method, if the `bool` is `true`, make your lazer move.